# How would I disable my range oven's timer?

Tags: oven

I have an *old* Magic Chef range oven that looks like this:

[image]

When the range oven is plugged in, the timer starts at 1:59. The timer beeps when that length of time has elapsed. I fiddled with the timer buttons and tried every possible configuration, but the only way to stop the timer is to 1) reset the timer to 1:59, or 2) unplug the range oven.

Is there any way to disable the timer permanently? Perhaps by taking it apart, or some other workaround?

A label on the oven door indicates a number of 8114p351-60, if that helps.

Comment: Does the oven work while the timer is running and stop when it times out?  The timer can probably be bypassed.  There should be a schematic showing the timer.  Take a copy to a repair shop for advice.

Comment: The oven works irregardless of whether the timer is running, but (I think) unplugging the oven causes the igniter to not work. Where do you find the schematic? I can't find the manual via google.

Comment: It should be inside the panel holding the timer or on the back of the unit.

Comment: @Jason after the 1:59 does the oven work?  How about 'plug it in, listen to the beep once, and never unplug it' as a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have an almost-as-old-as-yours Magic Chef oven, and the igniter and the oven light should work fine with the clock disconnected. Here's how to do it.

1. unscrew the back panel to get to the clock.
2. There will be two wires connecting to the clock: a white wire and a black wire that's daisy-chained to the light switch on the left side of the top panel.
3. disconnect both wires by wiggling their wire clamps and pulling until they come off.
4. cover the bare metal ends of both securely and thoroughly with electrical tape. This is very important!  If those wires contact any nearby metal you'll short the circuit at best, and at worst cause a fire-- unintended sparks around gas ranges are a shortcut to a very bad day.
5. I'd suggest taping the now-fully-insulated wires to the back of the clock panel so they won't be dangling in the back of the range where it might be hot enough to damage the insulation on the wires.

Comment: Step 0: ***unplug! ***. (Shouldn't have to say that, but...)

Comment: Wirenuts or heat shrink are better ways to cover the ends of wires than tape is.

Comment: I agree with ThreePhaseEel. Clip the terminals off the ends of the wire and use heat shrink tubing or a wire nut to cap them off. Tape has a tendency to dry out and release especially in a hot environment.

Answer (score -1):

You could add a switch between clock and timer to kill the power or remove the power to the timer.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This doesn't make sense as the answer to the original question.